# Python insertion sort with binary search not (but almost) working

Tags: python

As far as I can see, the binary search specified by the while loop should always continue searching until the min and max of the search space is equal. But on testing it, and always after having already sorted most of the items, it gets stuck in an infinite loop because `mx` somehow obtains the value `-2`.

I suppose I could change the condition of the while loop to patch that, but I'm trying to understand why it's behaving as it is, and have tried going over it with my eye and on paper but can't reproduce the event where `mx = -2`.

```
def insort(seq):
    for a in xrange(1, len(seq)):
        if seq[a] > seq[a - 1]:
            continue
        else:
            mn, mx = 0, a - 1
            while mn != mx:
                pivot = mn + ((mx - mn) / 2)
                if seq[a] > seq[pivot]:
                    mn = pivot + 1
                else:
                    mx = pivot - 1
            seq.insert(mn, seq.pop(a))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE**: I am using python 2.7.3 . I'm not sure if other versions of python have different results arising from division, so here's a heads up.

Several changes are required:

- Change `mn != mx` to `mn < mx`
- Change `pivot = mn + ((mx - mn) / 2)` statement to `pivot = int(math.floor((mn + mx) / 2))` or `pivot = mn + int(math.floor((mx - mn) / 2))` to prevent any kind of surprises when it comes down to division.
- Search interval indicated by `mn`, `mx` is changed to a half open interval, given by `[mn, mx)`, because that is something I'm more familiar with when it comes to a hand coded binary search. So `mx` should be set to `a` initially, and `mx` should be set to `pivot` instead of `pivot - 1` in the case where `seq[a] <= seq[pivot]` (iow, if the `if` test is `False`).

So the code with the edits should look like:

```
import math

def insort(seq):
    for a in xrange(1, len(seq)):
        if seq[a] > seq[a - 1]:
            continue
        else:
            mn, mx = 0, a
            while mn < mx:
                pivot = mn + int(math.floor(((mx - mn) / 2)))
                if seq[a] > seq[pivot]:
                    mn = pivot + 1
                else:
                    mx = pivot
            seq.insert(mn, seq.pop(a))
```

For the **original code**, I will give you an example where `mx` gets stuck at `-2`.

Given this list: `[10, 7, 8, 5, 13, 2, 6, 1, 50]`

Everything works fine until the element at index 5, which has a value of `2` (Verify this for yourself by adding some `print` statements). Since `seq[a] > seq[a-1]` is false (`2` is the smallest element so far), we enter the else branch of the if statement.

At this point:

```
seq = [5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 2, 6, 1, 50]
a = 5
mn = 0
mx = a - 1 = 4
```

Since `mn != mx` (`0 != 4`), we enter the while loop. `pivot` is set to `0 + ((4 - 0) / 2)` = `2`. Next we perform `if seq[a] > seq[pivot]`. `seq[a] = 2`, while `seq[pivot]` = `8` and `2 > 8` is `False`, so we go to the else branch and perform `mx = pivot - 1 = 2 - 1  = 1`

At this point:

```
seq = [5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 2, 6, 1, 50]
a = 5
mn = 0
mx = 1
```

We perform the check at the while loop again. `mn != mx` (`0 != 1`), so we go inside the body of the while loop. We set `pivot = 0 + ((1 - 0) / 2) = 0` (I am using python 2.7 to perform this division, so do verify at a repl), then perform the check `seq[a] > seq[pivot]` (`2 > 5`), which is `False`. Hence, we set `mx = pivot - 1 = 0 - 1 = -1`.

At this point:

```
seq = [5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 2, 6, 1, 50]
a = 5
mn = 0
mx = -1
```

Now, we perform the check at the while loop, `mn != mx` (`0 != -1`), so we enter the body of the while loop. `pivot = 0 + ((-1 - 0) / 2) = -1`. Then we perform the check `seq[a] > seq[pivot]` (`seq[5] > seq[-1]`, which compares the 5th element with the last element of `seq`, in other words `2 > 50`), and that is `False`. So `mx = pivot - 1 = -1 - 1 = -2`.

Now we've reached the final step:

```
seq = [5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 2, 6, 1, 50]
a = 5
mn = 0
mx = -2
```

At the while loop check, `mn != mx`, so we go on to `pivot = 0 + ((-2 - 0) / 2) = -1`. Observe that this is the same pivot as the above step. Then `seq[5] > seq[-1]` is performed (`2 > 50`), which is `False`. So `mx = pivot - 1 = -1 - 1 = -2`. And we end up in the same state as above. Which is why you see an infinite loop.

Finally, I just want to say that, binary search is a pretty tricky algorithm to code out since it's quite easy to make mistakes for the boundary indices. I've coded it by hand quite a lot of times and I still find it quite tricky. You might want to read this as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Hope that helps!